# CSS z-index not working as expected with angular animation

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, animation, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to implement a drag and drop in my application and want to identify the drop zones with text that will disappear when an item is added. For aesthetics I would like to use animate.css's bounce in animation when adding items and fade the text in and out as necessary, however I cannot seem to arrange it so the background text does not interfere with the position of the added/removed elements.

[This plunk illustrates the issue](http://plnkr.co/edit/B1WPqWsjtUzFDis3Xi5A?p=preview)

Any ideas on how to fix this sort of problem? I can't find a way to have the z-index respected. My only idea was to have the text set as the background image for the drop zones, but it feels like there must be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally somebody making drag-and-drop with AngularJS. :)

Could you make it in github and share it with us when you are  done?

To reply your question, outside `position:relative`, inside, `position:absolute`.

```
.well {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 50px;
}
.background {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 10;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

To make it as a directive, some css gotta be forced by directive, I think.

http://plnkr.co/edit/OAJuNXxYs05W1QYN0VOU?p=preview

Comment: This is great! Thanks so much for your help. Also, I didn't write the drag and drop, you can find it on [github here](https://github.com/ganarajpr/angular-dragdrop). You'll have to delete lines 33-37 for it to work in angular 1.2.

Answer (score 0):

From your Plunk, it looks like the background text is not absolutely-positioned. So the dropped element will flow after it in the container.

You should probably hide the background text immediately on drop. `drop` is a [Javascript dnd event](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_drag_drop.htm).

Comment: I believe this solution works for elements entering a drop area but not for elements leaving a drop area, because the text becomes visible again as soon as there are no elements in the array (before the bounce animation has finished).